# Type anyObject? does not conform to 'StringLiteralConvertible'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview, cloudkit

I am trying to add pictures stored as CKAssets to an array in a collection view, however my query to bring back the images is giving me an error that I can't figure out.  Can anyone help me out?

My code is:

```
class Query: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var matchedSelfie = [String]()

        let database = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
        var publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase

        let myQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "thecontainer", predicate: NSPredicate(value: "field1" === "field2"))

        var mySelfie = matchedSelfie

        publicDB.performQuery(myQuery, inZoneWithID: nil) {
            results, error in
            if error != nil {
                println(error)

            }
            else {
                for record in results {
                    var aselfie = mySelfie[(
                    aselfie: record.objectForKey("selfie") as String)]

                    mySelfie.append(aselfie)
                    return ()
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line `var aselfie = mySelfie[(aselfie: record.objectForKey("selfie") as String)]`?

Comment: That is the line that I thought was pulling back the assets from the field "selfie" out of iCloud.  (I'm a noob, so I may have it completely wrong)

Comment: I mean the `mySelfie[(aselfie:` part. Which method are you trying to call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `stringForKey:` to get the `String?` value of a `CKRecord`

```
for record in result c{
    if let aselfie = record.stringForKey("selfie") { //Optional binding
        mySelfie.append(aselfie) //Append to string array
    }
    return ()
}
```

**Important:** Arrays are Structs in Swift so you're actually creating a copy of matchedSelfie when you do `var mySelfie = matchedSelfie`.